# Zurb Foundation's Accordion is not WAI compatible

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Since it's not possible to register for the [Foundation Forum](https://foundation.zurb.com/forum) I hope somebody here can help.

It looks like the Zurb Accordion is not compliant with WAI. The accordion renders an element with the role `tablist` (`ul.accordion`. Inside this `li`s are created. Every of this `li`s consist of a link with the role `tab` and a div with the role `tabpanel`.

[As far as I understand](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-1/tabs.html)  the `tablist` should only contain `tab`s and the `tabpanel`s should be outside of the `tablist`.

Comment: Please open an issue at https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites

Comment: Issue is created: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/11659